# RedirectMatch example.com/post-slug to example.com/post/post-slug

Tags: regex, wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I have built a custom WordPress theme that displays posts in a modal from the home page.

I need to redirect from

```
http://example.com/my-post-slug
```

to

```
http://example.com/post/my-post-slug
```

I've tried to figure out RedirectMatch but with no luck. So far I tried this but it just causes an infinite loop:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/(.*)$ /post/$1
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this tweaked regex in the rule:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/([^/.]+)$ /post/$1
```

`[^/]+` will not match `/post/somepost` hence will not cause any redirect loop. Make sure to clear your browser cache.

Comment: This is redirecting my static front page. 

`example.com` goes to `example.com/post/index.php` and it says 'Too Many Redirects'

Comment: try updated rule after completely clearing browser cache.

Comment: after upgrading to the latest WordPress I am seeing a new issue. My custom structure it mysite.com/post/slug. I had setup a custom rewrite rule in my functions.php that would let me refresh the page but its not working anymore:

     add_rewrite_rule('^post/([^/]*)/?', 'index.php?page_id=5&post=$matches[1]', 'top');

Comment: For some reason now it just redirects me to the home page. Any ideas?

Comment: If you comment out this rule and retest, does it change the behavior?